# How to automatically update documents after index update in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have **Azure Search service** with some `indexes`, `indexers` and `SQL data sources`.
 `Data source` configured to use `SqlIntegratedChangeTrackingPolicy`, and it works fine, when any row in db updated, document updated as well.

Now I want to update `index` and add new field.
But after I do it, field contain no data, `indexer` ignores it, like he has nothing to add.

How can I force `indexer` to fill missing data?
Or the only way is to update manually each document?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the indexer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/reset-indexer)?

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Really did the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaurav is correct - to update documents that are already in the index, reset the indexer. You can reset directly in the Azure portal, indexer blade. For any new or updated SQL table rows with new field, the new field will be included automatically.